# Using existing AAD token to request token for Kusto

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory, azure-data-explorer

I'm trying to have a user log in to my bot (Microsoft bot framework) and make Kusto queries. I have been successful in getting a Graph JWT but I can't figure out how to then request Kusto access as well.

```
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-*********");
            var clientAppID = "974c5166-f8b5-466e-9552-*********";
            var secret = "[*SxczFa7qU*******************";
            var tokenForKusto = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
               "https://aznw.kusto.windows.net",
               new ClientCredential(clientAppID, secret),
               new UserAssertion(userToken));
```

I expect the `tokenForKusto` to be a valid token but instead it throws an exception.
`{"AADSTS500131: Assertion audience does not match the Client app presenting the assertion. The audience in the assertion was '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000' and the expected audience is '974c5166-f8b5-466e-9552-********' or one of the Application Uris of this application with App ID '974c5166-f8b5-466e-9552-********'(testbotbuilderAAD).\r\nTrace ID: 38515779-b858-4efc-8b03-e9f8ec810c00\r\nCorrelation ID: a136600d-66e0-44fc-8f24-d1fda6b4ba56\r\nTimestamp: 2019-07-19 17:23:27Z"}`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to use the token issued for Graph, but your application is not Graph. This flow will only work if and only if the client app ID (from the ClientCredentials) matches the audience of the token you are attempting to use.

Why would you be retrieving tokens for Graph anyway?
If you want to issue Kusto queries, you should use the cluster URI as the resource (e.g., "https://cluster.region.kusto.windows.net")